# Toolbar not responding to scroll in CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout

My view hierchy is straightforward:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <!-- another view -->

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

A fragment is added to the FrameLayout with the view:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
```

Scrolling the RecyclerView in the fragment has no effect on the toolbar. I was hoping it would have the same effect as https://i.stack.imgur.com/FoBYm.gif

Things I've tried:

1) Wrapping the FrameLayout in a NestedScrollView and adding the 
`app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` to it

2) Replacing the FrameLayout with a NestedScrollView

3) Wrapping the toolbar in a CollapsingToolbarLayout

4) Changing/adding scroll flags

Comment: Change the height of the `CoordinatorLayout` and the `FrameLayout` to `match_parent`.

Comment: Put the layout behaviour for the recyclerview

Comment: @krislarson no effect

Comment: I am having the same problem, did you find a solution finallly?

Answer (score -1):

I think the issue is that your RecyclerView does not have the layout_behavior attribute. It should look like:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:id="@+id/list_content"
     app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
```

I just recently implemented the collapsing toolbar as well. And based my approach on [this blog post](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout).

Answer (score -1):

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/background_light"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/main.appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/main.collapsing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">


            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/main.toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="8dp"
            android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:text="@string/lorem"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_comment_24dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/main.appbar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

you can replace NestedScrollView by your RecyclerView.

```
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout =
        (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_collapsing);

    collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
```

This a image of GIF:

[image]

Comment: why do i need an imageview?

Comment: @ono You can remove the imageview. I have already edited my answer. If my answer helped you, feel free to accept it :) !